# Chrome Date/Time parsing breaks in Mac & Mobile devices, Works fine in windows chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, javascript-objects, datetime-format

I have issue while parsing the date/Time in Mac and mobile devices.

```
new Date("2018-12-16T00:00:00")
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("de").format(new Date())
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("de").format(new Date("2018-12-16T00:00:00"))
```

Following code works fine in windows chrome browser, but fails to work in Mac chrome browser.

In Mac i have tested with safari, it works fine.

Getting error as "RangeError : Invalid time value"

I know its not a ISO standard format, to avoid locale issue we have made this custom format to work in all locale.

Now its works in Windows chrome and failed in "Mac Chrome"

Comment: I'm currently on Chrome 71 on MacOS 10.14.1 (Mojave) and cannot replicate the error above. The code above runs fine in the terminal. What specifically is not working?

Comment: Currently we are facing problem in "macOS 10.13: High Sierra (Lobo)". Is this a Javascript problem or browser problem.!

Comment: Sounds like a MacOS problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem resolved**

```
export const localeDay = (date, languageCode) => {
  try {
    if (new Date(date) instanceof Date && !isNaN(new Date(date))) {
      return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(languageCode).format(new Date(date));
    }
    return null;
  } catch (error) {
    logger(error.toString());
  }
};
```